# Is something wrong with my json variable?

Tags: javascript, php, json, linegraph

I have a javascript file that imports Google Visualization to draw a line graph:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


    var inputData =  [[1990,157894],[1991,173725],[1992,181227],[1993,183315]];

      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {        
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('number', 'Year');
            data.addColumn('number', 'January');
            data.addRows(inputData);


        var options = {
          title: 'Unemployed Statistics'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

After

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
```

I have an element that draws the graph:

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

This works fine and the graph is drawn fine with this. However, when I put my json variable into var inputData, no graph is drawn. It would look like this:

```
var inputData = <?php echo json_encode($json['unemployment'), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) ?>;
```

Why is nothing being drawn?

I run a print statement after I submit my form to check and see what `<?php echo json_encode($json['unemployment') ?>` is. Here is the output: [[1990,131337],[1991,160256],[1992,188129]] .

This output looks like it should easily work with the var inputData variable in my javascript code. However, nothing gets drawn. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: don't check the php output. do a "view source" in your browser to see if those numbers actually showed up in the generated page.

Comment: Yes, they are showing up in view source.

Comment: are you missing a ]?   json_encode($json['unemployment'])  Or should the ) be a ]?  json_encode($json['unemployment'],

Comment: var inputData =  <?php echo json_encode($json['unemployed'], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);?> ; ... This is what I currently have. My bad.

Comment: manually put in the generated data.   [[1990,286601],[1991,319983],[1992,362421],[1993,342919]]    Make sure that the data set is valid and if so that the line isn't just being generated outside of the view area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look here:
you have syntax error

```
<?php echo json_encode($json['unemployment'), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) 

$json['unemployment')
```

Comment: var inputData =  <?php echo json_encode($json['unemployment'], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);?> ;
I changed it. Still nothing is happening. There is a space where it looks the the image should be drawn, but nothing is there.

Comment: The array now is ok on the js source?

Comment: Yes i understand that but is the array ok? look at the source. and what happend if you write it hard-coded. is the graph work then?

Comment: This is what appears on the page source after I push submit on the form.... [[1990,286601],[1991,319983],[1992,362421],[1993,342919]]

Comment: If I manually put random numbers into var inputData such as [[1990,286601],[1991,319983],[1992,362421],[1993,342919]] then my graph works fine. But I need them to be gathered from user selections by using json.

Comment: Actually I messed up. I was still looking at my echo statement. When I took that out and looked at the page source, var inputData = null. So it isn't getting transfered to my javascript. Any idea why that is?

Comment: so unemployment is null for some reason. can you show your php code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39308/discussion-between-user2562125-and-dvir)